# Grabbing HTML source after delayed redirect

Tags: python, python-3.x, redirect, python-requests

I am trying to grab the HTML source of a website with Python. However, when you visit any page on the site there is a delayed redirect almost like a loading screen. Whenever I do a `requests.get(url)` I end up grabbing that loading screen and not what comes after it. I am using the Requests library. Is there a way to make the request wait till after the redirect? The redirect is about 3 seconds.

Here is the code I use:

```
import Requests
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.text)
```

Comment: Requests may not be the best tool for this if the site is using javascript to render the content after the loading screen. Do you have the url of the website you wish to grab the source of?

Comment: The redirect is most likely executed *in the browser* because the browser executes Javascript code. Either use a headless browser to do the same or reverse engineer the javascript to load the destination directly.

Comment: https://kissanime.to/Anime/Steins-Gate-Dub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect is probably done by your browser, not by the server. There are 2 common ways: ["meta refresh"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) or Javascript.

For the former you can parse the HTML response using something like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), examine it for a meta refresh tag, extract the destination URL, then retrieve it with a second request.

It's more difficult if the redirect is done with Javascript as there are many ways in which the redirect could be done.

Either way is a bit messy, so your best bet would be to use something like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) which basically lets you script your browser so that you can let a browser do the meta refresh/javascript redirect for you.

Comment: When I use selenium and try to print the html source from `driver.page_source` I get an error.

   ` [Py3] C:\Users\Evan\PythonProjects>python test.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(html_source)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Miniconda3\envs\Py3\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in e
ncode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position
7006: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: It means that your terminal can't display that character because it can not represent '\u2026' (horizontal ellipsis) in your terminal's encoding, which is cp437. Use a modern terminal encoding such as Windows-1251 or UTF-8. Instead of printing the html source, write it to a file instead. Then you should be able to inspect it.

Comment: Or `import codec` then use `page.encode('utf-8')` then it will let me print the html.

Comment: @Gamegoofs2: you don't need to `import codec` to do that, but yes, that's another way to look at the page.

Answer (score -1):

you can turn off the default auto redirect characteristic, and get the object page by  request the web page that indicated in r.history where store the redirect location